# scp error--syntax, or something else?

Tags: scp

I am trying to use scp to copy various files from my work machine to my personal. I use the code:

```
scp usernamework@workcomputer:~/directory/to/file \
  usernamepersonal@personalcomputer:~/Directory/to/copied/file
```

When I enter the code I am prompted for my work computer password. I enter the password and the error is:

```
could not resolve hostname(personal computer)
```

Is there a syntax error in my code-or is there something else going on?

Comment: that error mean you use hostname to your personal computer which is invalid, try to use ip aaddress

Answer (score 0):

If you specify two remote hosts, it will connect to the first one and from there it will connect to the second one. The second hostname is probably not resolvable/visible from the first one and therefore it fails. There are few possibilities you can do:

- Connect to your `personal` computer and do a transfer with only one remote:

  ```
  scp usernamework@workcomputer:~/directory/to/file ~/Directory/to/copied/file
  ```
- Use `-3` switch, which will connect to both of the ends from your current computer:

  ```
  scp -3 usernamework@workcomputer:~/directory/to/file \
    usernamepersonal@personalcomputer:~/Directory/to/copied/file
  ```